# how I could create a dot method in groovy for reduce code?

Tags: java, methods, groovy

for example I have a code like this

```
.toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat()
```

and I need create a method like this

```
.formatx()
```

that have the same function

this is my hash

```
def test=[:]
7.times {test[1]= test[1].toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat() +5.5 }
```

please help me

Comment: What kind of object are you using to do `.toString()`?

Comment: a hash test[] that in some cases the value is number and null

Comment: I transform to string  for replace the null value and convert in number with to float again

Comment: but is some large and my code looks ugly

Comment: Provide an example of the hash.

Comment: I put my hash in my last edit

Comment: Im trying to reduce because I use a lot of hash and function that I need  change the null value

Comment: Your example can simply be written as `7.times { test[1]= (test[1] ?: 0f) + 5.5 }`

Comment: yes  put this can be some complicated for more large function

Comment: I think that dot function can be result more helpful for reduce code

Comment: Yes that can be done using `metaClass` for example `String.metaClass.formatx = { delegate.toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat()  }`, but I do not see a rationale doing that way. I was trying to find out a more comprehensive way to address your problem. The problem with metaClass implementation is that, all null values will be treated the same way, that is, convert to `0.0` float value.

Comment: maybe but this result if I convert to string first  this answer is helpfully for me very thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution

```
 import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject

    String.metaClass.formatx = { -> delegate.toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat()  }
     NullObject.metaClass.formatx = { -> delegate.toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat() }
    Integer.metaClass.formatx = { -> delegate.toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat() }

    m2= 4.formatx()
    m= "4".formatx()

     println null.formatx()
```